# How to system.out.print the id of the item selected in the combo box that is from a database?

Tags: java, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8

//this the code for adding the items(from the database) in the combobox

```
for(Position tempAre: this.pos)
            {
                ps = tempAre;
                posCombo.addItem(ps.getPosName());
            }
```

Comment: What framework does you combo box come from?

Comment: netbeans ui framework

Comment: Since Netbeans can use Swing, JavaFX and AWT, that's not lot of help, unless you're using the Netbeans Application API

Comment: how about swing api.

Comment: [`JComboBox#getSelectedItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem--) will return an object instance of the selected item, which you'll need to cast back to your target value